# Facebook/Instagram Comments Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I need your help in order to find a tutorial or any other information regarding the scraping with Python (Legally: Because this is a part of a data collection for my thesis so I will need the legal ways to scrap the data please).
Whould you please help me to find out the usefull sources to realize this ?

Comment: Facebook offers an API. Have you checked it out?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/web-scraping-instagram-with-selenium-python-b8e77af32ad4
Medium usually provides fairly good instructions.

Comment: But still this method is not approved by Instagram and it says instagram can ban the user. Since I want to add this part to my thesis too I think it would not work in my case.